# How to validate email for members?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I've got `validates_presence_of :email` in my `User` model. My user model also has a boolean `member` column, to determine whenter a user is a member or a regular user.

Regular users can sign up without an email. But when they register for a member account, they need to provide an email.

The problem is when a user signs up as a regular, validation will trigger stating that `:email` is blank. How do I go about this?

Would be awesome if validation had named scopes too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to happen?  If a regular user with a blank email signs up as a member, *shouldn't* that trigger a validation error?

Comment: Sorry, made some changes to make it clearer. Basically, a user who wants to sign up as a regular shouldn't trigger an email validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action that your member sign-up form calls can explicitly set user.member=true, then JacobM's answer will work, namely,

```
validates_presence_of :email, :if => :member
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, it should be as simple as

```
validates_presence_of :email, :if => :member
```

Comment: Well, that will only trigger if user is ALREADY a member. This means, on the member's sign up form, if the user decides to leave the email blank, validation won't trigger.

Comment: I don't see why. The validation isn't triggered until you try to save the object. Presumably you'll have set the member flag by then. It's not fundamentally different from "if you said Yes to question 1, then question 2 is required", which I do all the time this way.